# Retrieve the instance of runnable from completablefuture

Tags: java, completable-future

I am running a list of runnables using `ExecutorService` and collating all results using `CompletableFuture`. I would like to correlate which instance of `CompletableFuture` ran a specific runnable.

Here is the actual code

```
public static void runTasks(final List<Runnable> tasks, final int threadCount) {
    final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
    final CompletableFuture<?>[] futures = tasks.stream()
            .map(task -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(task, es))
            .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
    try {
        CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join();
        es.shutdown();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

I have the results stored in futures variable 
`CompletableFuture<?>[] futures`

Is there a way to get the class name of runnable whose result is stored in an instance of future?

I am trying to print the individual task result as follows:

```
for (CompletableFuture future : futures) {
    final boolean taskCompletedSuccessfully = future.isDone() && !(future.isCompletedExceptionally() || future.isCancelled());
    LOGGER.info("Task completion status for {} : {}", <runnable class name>, (taskCompletedSuccessfully ? "SUCCESSFUL" : "FAILED"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to retrieve any information about the `Runnable` because the `CompletableFuture` does not hold any reference to it.

You will thus have to store the future and the runnable (or its class name) together in some `Pair` implementation, e.g.:

```
final List<Pair<Runnable, CompletableFuture<Void>>> futures = tasks.stream()
        .map(task -> new Pair<>(task, CompletableFuture.runAsync(task, es)))
        .collect(toList());
try {
    CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.stream().map(Pair::getB).toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)).join();
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.warn("At least one future failed", e);
}
es.shutdown();
futures.forEach(pair -> {
    CompletableFuture<Void> future = pair.getB();
    final boolean taskCompletedSuccessfully = !future.isCompletedExceptionally();
    log.info("Task completion status for {} : {}", pair.getA().getClass().getSimpleName(), (taskCompletedSuccessfully ? "SUCCESSFUL" : "FAILED"));
});
```

A few notes:

- if any of the tasks fails, the `allOf()` will fail as well. You probably don't want to `exit()` in that case – otherwise you will always have only successful tasks logged;
- after `allOf().join()`, you are guaranteed that `isDone()` holds true for all tasks, no need to check it;
- `isCancelled()` (which is not possible here) implies `isCompletedExceptionally()`

Comment: Thanks for confirming my assumption.  This should work.